# How to use SSE(server sent event) in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-sent-events

If I don't used express , can I use SSE?
when I used

```
context.eventSource = new EventSource(`/`);
```

I have an error
`EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

I don't know what eventSource url can I use.
I guess .vue file can't be used for SSE

Can anyone help me? Really thanks.

Comment: google `SSE nuxt.js` ... https://github.com/nuxt/rfcs/issues/36 is the first link - https://content.nuxtjs.org/configuration/#apiprefix mentions SSE, but can't find other details in the nuxtjs documentation

Comment: @Bravo I had try, but It's not useful. It have eventSource error too. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the content type response header to be "text/event-stream"